# Tenants Not Loading When Adding Azure AD Service Dependency

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to add an AAD service dependency to a new ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC) project. I went to Connected Services, clicked on "Add a service dependency" and chose Microsoft identity platform. The next step installed additional software and asked me to retry. So, after the software was installed, I retried and was presented with a dialog to "Select an Azure Directory application to configure." This dialog just hangs trying to load the AAD Tenants, of which there is one. I've attempted several different new projects with the same result.
[image]